# Can't access apache error logs

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, logs

My Ubuntu vitual server wen't offline. I rebooted it and now want to debug what happened.

I can browse to `/etc/log` but if I try `cd apache2` it says Permission denied. I'm sure my user account has priviliges.
I also tried `sudo cd apache2` which gives the the error `sudo: cd: command not found`

How can I access the apache logs? I also tried via sftp without success

PS I am new to linux and virtual servers, but I am keen to learn everything I can.

Comment: Try `sudo -i` then `cd apache2`.

Comment: @Wilf it then says -bash: cd: apache2: No such file or directory

Comment: sudo su them access

Comment: The logs are located under var not etc. You need to go to /var/log/apache2. If you dont have the rights to enter the folder, open a root terminal. do sudo -i and the go to cd /var/log/apache2 and take a look at the files there. Good luck...

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need to add your username to the group adm

```
sudo usermod -aG adm YourUserName
```

You can then access the logfiles as normal user without sudo.

Comment: Thanks, this worked and made me able to actually browse to directory.

Comment: I had to log in / out of my user session for this permission to take effect.

Comment: it working but you Need log-out from ssh and log-in again. then you have access.

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
sudo cat /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

Comment: Thanks wojox, but is there a more permanent solution? Like being able to navigate to the apache2 folder?

Answer (score 2):

You can log in as root user:

```
sudo su
```

And then you are able to do:

```
cd apache2
```

Comment: That works, thanks, although is it permanent or will su only have elevated privileges for the current session?

Comment: I like the solution by @rechengehirn as it's permanent.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not permanent.